# Android Consumed Memory Size Limit

Tags: android, memory, out-of-memory, heap-memory

My app has tabbed view and It has 4 tabs, and these tab has a relatively a lot of thing to do because of "tabbed view - tab change animation" it load every tab on this activity.

so app consumes about 170-250 Mb memory. 
With *android:largeHeap="true"* and *"minSdkVersion 14";*

- Could it be a problem on low memory devices?
- Is there any memory distribution chart for all android devices, like %70 is bigger than 790MB and vs...
- If anyone has experience on this issue, Could you please suggest maximum heap size without a problem.

PS: In this app: I am not dealing with big Bitmaps or other files.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

```
you can try for XML layout also see bellow link for more info....I hope you will get solutions from this link....
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
and try it for tablet
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
app:tabGravity="fill"
app:tabMode="fixed"/>
.
http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/
http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment Nakum, I will try and inform you about the changes asap. But my question is actually about is this size ok or not?